# Differences between Uses-Permission and Permissions tag in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android

What is the difference between `Uses-Permission` and `Permissions` tag in **AndroidManifest.xml** .
I understood `uses-permission` tag as it is used to  access Internet,Location from our application. But I did not understand when and why should we use permissions tag in **Manifest** file and what is  its difference from `uses-permission`.

Answer (score 92):

Quoting the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html):

> To enforce your own permissions, you
>   must first declare them in your
>   `AndroidManifest.xml` using one or more
>   `<permission>` tags. For example, an application that wants to control who can start one of its activities could declare a permission for this operation as follows:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.me.app.myapp" >

    <permission android:name="com.me.app.myapp.permission.DEADLY_ACTIVITY"
        android:label="@string/permlab_deadlyActivity"
        android:description="@string/permdesc_deadlyActivity"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.COST_MONEY"
        android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />

</manifest>
```

Hence, `<uses-permission>` is when your application is seeking the user's permission to use some feature, while `<permission>` is when your application is requiring other apps to seek the user's permission to use some feature of yours.

Comment: How a third party app who is trying to use some feature on my app should obtain my DEADLY_ACTIVITY permission? Should the 3rd party declare on its manifest something like this ? <uses-permission  android:name=com.me.app.myapp.permission.DEADLY_ACTIVITY>  ??

Comment: @AKh: That is correct. If you have additional questions on this topic, please use the "Ask Question" link in the upper right, rather than commenting on a two-year-old answer.

Comment: Can anyone give me example of above answer?

Comment: @UnKnown: Few developers need to define custom permissions. Unless they are implementing a suite of apps, or an app with an SDK, a custom permission is not necessary and may be harmful. [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.6/Permissions/CustomDangerous) has two app modules, where `app` defines a custom `<permission>` and `client` has the corresponding `<uses-permission>` element.

Comment: Can you also give me a little intro about `android:permission` attribute? I searched a lot but can't fine the answer. Have you any link? even I failed to understand Android manifest document about it.

Comment: @UnKnown: You use that to say that a particular component (activity, service, receiver, provider) can only be used if the client holds the named permission. See [this line](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v8.6/Permissions/CustomDangerous/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L20) in the sample app that I linked to. "even I failed to understand Android manifest document about it" -- this stuff is covered in various Android app development books, FWIW.

Comment: Thanks. Can you share 1 or 2 books, you think is good for such stuff?

Comment: Thanks I can't subscribe right now because I'm collecting $ for my Uni fee. I will try within few months. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

- `<permission>` is for defining a custom permission.
- `<uses-permission>` is for using a permission in your app.

You may also be interested in [security problems with custom permissions](https://www.ndss-symposium.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/25/2018/02/ndss2018_08-4_Tuncay_paper.pdf) as of Feb. 2018. Their explanation of permissions in section 2 seemed far more clear to me than the documentation.