# Android Studio XML namespace not registered

Tags: android, xml, uri, xml-namespaces

so i've been working on a project pretty fine until some days ago. My XML file suddenly showed some errors. The "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" just went missing. Well... it wasn't delete but marked red. It says the URI is not registered and i tried to rewrite it with autocomplete (in case the namespace changed somehow) but it wasn't there. I looked in the settings if someone put it on ignore list or something like that but it was not. So here is my complete XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="de.test.android.tea.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<!-- Permission to save Robotium screenshots -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />

<!-- Permission to register as a camera app -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<instrumentation
    android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:targetPackage="de.telekom.android.tea" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />

    <!-- Camera mockup -->
    <activity
        android:name="de.telekom.android.tea.test.robotium.stub.CameraStub"
        android:label="Emma Camera Stub" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Gallery mockup -->
    <activity
        android:name="de.telekom.android.tea.test.robotium.stub.GalleryStub"
        android:label="Emma Gallery Stub" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/image" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Furthermore are android:versionCode, android:versionName, android:allowBackup, android:icon and data android:mimeType marked red too with the comment "Attribute not allowed here" (last one says Element not allowed here) and android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner, de.test.android.tea, de.test.android.tea.test.robotium.stub.CameraStub and de.test.android.tea.test.robotium.stub.GalleryStub marked with the comment "Cannot resolve symbol"

The XML file is used to give permissions to some stubs for automated testing and I'm using Android Studio 0.8.10 atm. I appreciate ever little hint.

**Edit:** I have a second AndroidManifest.xml in the Application Module which is working fine. It is just the one in the ApplicationTest module. I recently saw that some of my folders in the test module say "test resources root" and if i move it in one of those folders the namespace is available but then some of the targetpackages are not working.

Comment: Maybe you have some internet connectivity problem? Are you behind a proxy? Password changed lately?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning project and rebuilding?  Have you tried closing the IDE and restarting?

Comment: More information may be available at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323777/android-namespace-missing?rq=1

Comment: since the other manifest is working just fine i wouldn't say that i have connectivity problems and nothing changed such as passwords or proxies. yes i tried cleaning and rebuilding the project but it still remains. if found that post already but it didn't help :/