# Permission remove from one flavor

Tags: android, android-productflavors

I have a problem. I read a lot of answers about it, but it seems not working for me. I have an app with two flavors. The first (1) flavor contains in the manifest file two permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

The second (2) app contains these permissions inside the manifest:

```
<permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
    tools:node="remove"/>
<permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
    tools:node="remove"/>
```

And inside the main folder there is another manifest without any permission.
When I install the 2 app I always get the question about the permissions (that should be removed). I do not know why the "merge" does not remove these two permission from the second flavor?! How can I fix it? Thank you for your attention. Feel free to rate down my question.

Answer (score 0):

You're using uses-permission in the first and permission in the second. Permission and uses-permission are not the same. Take a look at this: [uses-permission vs permission for android permissions in the manifest.xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450839/uses-permission-vs-permission-for-android-permissions-in-the-manifest-xml-file)